# ListView or false method to get the result

Tags: java, android, listview

```
package eu.andykrzemien.dog4u;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

class Size {
  private int id;
  private String SizeName;

  public Size(int id, String sizeName) {
    this.id = id;
    SizeName = sizeName;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getSizeName() {
    return SizeName;
  }
  public void setSizeName(String sizeName) {
   SizeName = sizeName;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return getId()+" "+getSizeName();
  }
}

class Activities {
  private int id;
  private String ActivityName;

  public Activities(int id, String activityName) {
    this.id = id;
    ActivityName = activityName;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getActivityName() {
    return ActivityName;
  }

  public void setActivityName(String activityName) {
    ActivityName = activityName;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return getId()+ " "+getActivityName();
  }
}


class Children {
  private int id;
  private String ChildrenName;

  public Children(int id, String childrenName) {
    this.id = id;
    ChildrenName = childrenName;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getChildrenName() {
    return ChildrenName;
  }
  public void setChildrenName(String childrenName) {
    ChildrenName = childrenName;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return getId()+" "+getChildrenName();
  }
}



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
  ListView sizeList;
  ListView activityList;
  ListView childrenList;
  Button button;
  public static final String TAG = "MyActivity";


  public void inItListViews() {
  sizeList= findViewById(R.id.sizeList);
  activityList= findViewById(R.id.activityList);
  childrenList= findViewById(R.id.childrenList);
}
public void dogMatches() {

  Size s1 = new Size(1,"Miniature");
  Size s2 = new Size(2,"Small");
  Size s3 = new Size(3,"Medium");
  Size s4 = new Size(4,"Large");
  Size s5 = new Size(5,"Giant");

  Size [] size = new Size[]{s1,s2,s3,s4,s5};
  ArrayAdapter<Size> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,size);
  this.sizeList.setAdapter(adapter1);

  Activities a1 = new Activities(1,"Lazy");
  Activities a2 = new Activities(2,"Light Active");
  Activities a3 = new Activities(3,"Very Active");

  Activities[] activities = new Activities[]{a1,a2,a3};
  ArrayAdapter<Activities> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,activities);
  this.activityList.setAdapter(adapter2);

  Children c1 = new Children(1,"Like");
  Children c2 = new Children(2,"Doesn't matter");

  Children[] children = new Children[]{c1,c2};
  ArrayAdapter<Children> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,children);
  this.childrenList.setAdapter(adapter3);

}
  public void processResult() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Result button clicked");
    int pos1= sizeList.getCheckedItemPosition();
    int pos2 = activityList.getCheckedItemPosition();
    int pos3 = childrenList.getCheckedItemPosition();

    Size sSelected= (Size) sizeList.getItemAtPosition(pos1);
    Activities aSelected=(Activities) activityList.getItemAtPosition(pos2);
    Children cSelected=(Children) childrenList.getItemAtPosition(pos3);
    if(sSelected!=null && aSelected!=null && cSelected!=null){
      Log.d(TAG,"result "+ sSelected.getSizeName()+" : "+ aSelected.getActivityName()+ " " + cSelected.getChildrenName());

      String petSeeker = yourBest(sSelected,aSelected,cSelected);

      Toast.makeText(this,petSeeker,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
      Toast.makeText(this,"Please Select Something",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

  }
  public void buttonPressed() {
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        processResult();
      }
    });
  }

 private String yourBest(Size s, Activities a, Children c) {
    String doThis;
    if(s.getSizeName().equalsIgnoreCase("small")
        && a.getActivityName().equalsIgnoreCase("lazy")
        && c.getChildrenName().equalsIgnoreCase("like")){
      Toast.makeText(this,"Chihuahua",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      doThis="Chihuahua";
    }
    else if(s.getSizeName().equalsIgnoreCase("small")
        && a.getActivityName().equalsIgnoreCase("light active")
        && c.getChildrenName().equalsIgnoreCase("like")){
      doThis="Labrador";
    } else{
      doThis="Find a cat";
    }
    return  doThis;
  }


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inItListViews();
    dogMatches();
    buttonPressed();
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  }

}
```

The app is running but the problem is that I can't get the result of three listViews. Is it something with the ListView or with the method? After pressing button I get only else message. Maybe there is some method to check the listView because maybe they aren't coded with the press of the mouse. I'm really stuck and need at least some advice not a ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think it will be better without implementing `View.OnClickListener`, because you don't use it. Second - you can put a breakpoint at:

```
int pos1 = sizeList.getCheckedItemPosition();
```

Debug it and then you will see what is going wrong.
And last, I suggest creating a custom interface that will allow you to find out what position was checked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getCheckedItemPosition()` to get the position of the selected list item, use `listView.setOnItemClickListener()`

So you can remove below statements, and make po1-pos3 as global fields

```
    int pos1= sizeList.getCheckedItemPosition();
    int pos2 = activityList.getCheckedItemPosition();
    int pos3 = childrenList.getCheckedItemPosition();
```

As below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    int pos1, pos2, pos3;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inItListViews();
    dogMatches();
    buttonPressed();

    sizeList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            pos1 = position;
        }
    });

    activityList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            pos2 = position;
        }
    });


    childrenList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            pos3 = position;
        }
    });
  }
```

And to get a list item for a position:

```
sizeList.getAdapter().getItem(pos1);
activityList.getAdapter().getItem(pos2);
childrenList.getAdapter().getItem(pos3);
```